# If one complex number is equal to another, does that mean their real and imaginary parts are equal?

Tags: complex-numbers

Example
$$\sqrt{(x + 1)² + y²} = (x+2)+i (y + 2)$$
here in LHS, $i=0$, therefore in RHS, is $y+2=0$ too?

Thank you

Comment: It is not right to say $i=0,$ but it is correct to say the imaginary part of the left side is $0$, and hence to say $y+2=0.$

Comment: The correct way to say this is, since the left side is real, the right side has no imaginary component, thus $y+2=0$.

Comment: In general, you first need to represent $\sqrt{z}$ as a complex number $a+bi$. Then you can compare real and imaginary part. here $\sqrt{z}=a+0\cdot i$.

Comment: For what it's worth, such problems are not usually presented to students of Complex Analysis, in the format that you presented your question.  Perhaps your question is based on an underlying problem where you made an analytical mistake, or perhaps there is a typo (somewhere).

Comment: Thank you for the help, sirs